# Developing TCP/IP stack in user mode

Tags: networking, network-programming, network-protocols, tcp

Is there any library helping in developing TCP/IP stack in user mode or any implementation of that? What about LWIP?
http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lwip/

Answer (score 0):

[NetBSD RUMP](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/rump/) project allows building NetBSD and it's TCP/IP stack as a user application. BSD networking stack is arguably the reference TCP/IP stack implementation, so it's almost as good as it gets. It also comes with extensive implementation docs in form of [author's Ph.D. thesis](http://lib.tkk.fi/Diss/2012/isbn9789526049175/isbn9789526049175.pdf)

Comment: I did build it on Linux about a year ago. It should still be doable today.